# Namespace or type 'Twilio' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to use the Twilio API in my unity project but when I try to build in unity I get the error: namespace or type 'Twilio' could not be found (are you missing using directive or reference?)
Now I've loaded the twilio package (v 5.27.2) through Visual studio and it works fine there its just Unity that can't seem to find it. 
Can someone explain to me whats going on and how to fix this? 
I've provided some screenshots showing the [error,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l7fi.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qqYw.jpg) [,and Unity configuration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chiKX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your application code is compiled by Unity itself, not by Visual Studio. You need to make Unity aware of any external DLL libraries. To make Unity aware of an external DLL, just place it inside of the Assets directory in your Unity Project.